# How to read this type of json response containing \u0000*\u0000_translate

Tags: php, json

Can any one help me to read this type of json response.

```
{"\u0000*\u0000_translate":
 {
  "app_text_newcomer":"Newcomer",
  "app_text_senior":"Senior",
  "app_text_mostsenior":"Most Senior",
  "app_text_results":"Result",
  "app_text_result":"Result",
  "app_text_agenda":"Agenda",
  "app_text_dbvg":"Dbvg"
 },
 "0":{}
}
```

how can i get this value **\u0000*\u0000_translate**

Comment: If you just want to see what character it is you can pase it here and click "JSON to XML" : http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like JSON, so use [json_decode](http://php.net/json_decode) to get a PHP object or associative array.

Edit: Having just tried it, I see your problem. json_decode() can't handle nulls in the data, so you should file a bug about that.

Workaround: Preprocess \u0000 to some sentinel value you can later replace for a real null, [such as this](http://ideone.com/dzvok1):

```
$json = '{"\u0000*\u0000_translate": { "app_text_newcomer":"Newcomer", "app_text_senior":"Senior", "app_text_mostsenior":"Most Senior", "app_text_results":"Result", "app_text_result":"Result", "app_text_agenda":"Agenda", "app_text_dbvg":"Dbvg"}, "0":{}}';

$json = str_replace('\u0000', 'XNULLX', $json);

$arr = json_decode($json, true);
foreach ($arr as $k => $v) {
    if (strpos($k, 'XNULLX') !== false) {
        unset($arr[$k]);
        $k = str_replace('XNULLX', "\0", $k);
        $arr[$k] = $v;
    }
}

echo var_export($arr, true);
```